# Unable to cast text with Spinner in xml file

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, spinner

I'm to new to android and I'm trying to develop an UI ,but it is giving me the following error,where I'm developing UI that contains text beside to that spinner...

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Spinner cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

and  my setting.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/minute"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mile"
        android:layout_below="@+id/time"
        android:text="@string/min" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/distance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/time"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="@string/Distance" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/notification"
        android:layout_below="@+id/distance"
        android:text="@string/mile"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/minute"
        android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:text="@string/Notifications"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/notification"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mile"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:text="@string/Time" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/distanceview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/time"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/distance"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mile" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/timeview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/notification"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/distanceview"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/time" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timeview"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my java code

```
public class SettingsActivity extends SherlockActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private TextView distance, time;
    private Spinner spin;
    String spin_val;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        addDistanceRadioButtons();
        addTimeRadioButtons();
    }

    public void addDistanceRadioButtons() {
        spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.distanceview);
        final String[] item = { "0.1", "0.2", "0.4", "0.6", "0.8", "1.0", "1.2" }
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                spin_val = item[position];

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
        ArrayAdapter<String> spin_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.settings, item);
        spin.setAdapter(spin_adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is ur java code???

Comment: post your code and full logcat

Comment: clean your project after run your project...

Comment: please post your code of java class

Answer (score 0):

It may Cause Because of You Are Trying to get the Spinner As a TextView

Its seems that you have did code like:

```
Spinner mSpinner = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.spinner);
```

Instead, it should be casted properly as:

```
Spinner mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById (R.id.spinner);
```

Or

You may use `Spinner` id instaed of `TextView` Id

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Your Problem @ this line: the id `distance` is `TextView` not Spinner

```
 spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.distance);
```

I Think You need to use id `distanceview` instead od `distance`

Comment: then what should i do yar...,please give me suggestion

Comment: I have Updated my Post. Please check that in your Activity.

Comment: I even google and i got this link and i have read ,that that is not my problem...

Comment: Then Share your Activity.Then only we can find the issue.

Comment: even i tried yar,when i click on that button the activity is getting closed and getting the same exception....

Comment: There is no chance.Try to clean and run your project.

Comment: Tried but not gettg :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you give wrong ID to spinner. Maybe you gave text id to spinner that's why you are getting this. If you paste your Java code here then we will also see that mistake.

Or just clean your project after run your project. Sometimes some views keep their resource id and mash up all ids, so just clean and run.

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.distance);
```

should be

```
spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.distanceview);
```